# How to refer to a file in %APPDATA%\Folder in AutoIt?

Tags: script, autoit

I need to refer to a file in AutoIt, let's call its location `%APPDATA%\folder\file.txt`

How can I call to it in AutoIt? I've seen `%APPDATA%` referred as @AppDataCommonDir in it, but I can't get the full path right.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@AppDataCommonDir` refers to the All Users application data folder. If you want the Application Data folder for the current Windows user, you should use `@AppDataDir`.

The `File.au3` file contains a user-defined function (`_PathFull`) to build a path, using a relative path and a known full path. You can **#include** this file to gain access to this function.

Here's a script to build the complete path that you mentioned and display it in a message box.

```
#include <File.au3>

Local $filePath
$filePath = _PathFull("Folder\File.txt", @AppDataDir)

MsgBox (0, "Path", $filePath)
```

Running this script should create a message box similar to the following:

[image: sample message box from AutoIt]

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick!
I used your code to run using the $filepath variable.

Comment: If only all answers on SO would be this clear...